# Ratio of convex functions with dominating derivatives is convex?

Tags: probability, analysis, functions

Let $f,g:\mathbb [0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ satisfy $f^{(n)}(x)\geq g^{(n)}(x)>0$ for all $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ and $x\in [0,\infty)$. In particular, $f\geq g> 0$ are increasing and convex (from the case when $n=1,2$). Further, assume $f^{(n)}(x)\geq f^{(n-1)}(x)$ and $g^{(n)}(x)\geq g^{(n-1)}(x)$ for all $n\geq1$.

Question: Is $\frac{f}{g}$ convex?

This seems true, once I draw a picture, but I couldn't convince myself thoroughly. Can anybody help? Thanks very much.

Comment: $f$ and $g$ increasing and convex are hyphotesis?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention one more assumption: $f^{(n)}(x)\geq f^{(n-1)}(x)$ and $g^{(n)}(x)\geq g^{(n-1)}(x)$ for all $n\geq1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no necessarily. Note that

$$
f=g+ h \mbox{ where } h^{(n)}(x)\ge0 \;\; \forall n \ge 0
$$
And $\frac{f}{g}$ is convex iff $\frac{h}{g}$ is convex.

Now suppose $g(x)=e^x$. Then we need $h$ such that  $h^{(n)}(x)\ge0 \; \forall n$ and

$$
\left(\frac{h}{e^x}\right)''=\frac{h''(x)-2h'(x)+h(x)}{e^x}<0 \mbox{ somewhere }
$$ 
Set $h(x)=ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants. Then
$$
h''(x)-2h'(x)+h(x)= 0-2a+ax+b=a(x-2)+b
$$
which is negative in $x=2-\frac{b}{a}-\varepsilon$.

.

I think that given any $g$, we can choose $h$ such that

$$
\left(\frac{h}{g}\right)''<0 
$$
but surely it's a little more difficult to prove.

Comment: Thanks very much.  It helps.  What about under the further assumption: $f^{(n)}(x)\geq f^{(n-1)}(x)$ and $g^{(n)}(x)\geq g^{(n-1)}(x)$ for all $n\geq1$?

Comment: One such an example would be $f(x)=\exp(cx)$ with $c\in(1,\infty)$.